# What slokas/mantras needs to told while offering food to god

Tags: mantras, puja

While it is a normal practice to prepare food and offer it to god before eating. I would like to know what slokas/mantras needs to told while offering food to god. Also if there are any specific procedures to be followed, Pl. share the same.

Comment: you can see here in my answer http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3241/should-we-chant-mantras-before-eating-food/8733#8733

Comment: @Bhavin , the information was very helpful, however, it mentions the mantra we need to say before having food. Can the same be told when we offer neivedyam.

Comment: yes you can...also Krishna said in BG 9.27 Whatever you do, whatever you eat, whatever you offer or give away, and whatever austerities you perform – do that, O son of Kuntī, as an offering to Me. http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/9/27